# `pipenv install` fails with " KeyError: 'url' "

Tags: python, pipenv

### What I Want To Do

I want to create a virtual environment using pipenv.

### Problem

In order to create a virtual environment, I used pipenv. However, even though I tried to create a virtual environment on an empty directory, I get an error.

```
> cd C:\Users\namae\OneDrive\Document 
> mkdir test 
> cd test 
> py -m pipenv install
```

Note that I don't pass the path of python (because it was recommended when I installed it...) and that is why I use `py -m`.

The error message is as follows:

```
Creating a virtualenv for this project…
Pipfile: C:\Users\namae\OneDrive\Document\Pipfile
Using C:/Users/namae/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe (3.8.4) to create virtualenv…
[ ===] Creating virtual environment...created virtual environment CPython3.8.4.final.0-64 in 1729ms
  creator CPython3Windows(dest=C:\Users\namae\.virtualenvs\Document-93FUvPFU, clear=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=C:\Users\namae\AppData\Local\pypa\virtualenv)
    added seed packages: pip==20.2.2, setuptools==49.6.0, wheel==0.35.1
  activators BashActivator,BatchActivator,FishActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator,XonshActivator

Successfully created virtual environment!
Virtualenv location: C:\Users\namae\.virtualenvs\Document-93FUvPFU
Creating a Pipfile for this project…
Pipfile.lock not found, creating…
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
Locking [packages] dependencies…
Updated Pipfile.lock (1f10f9)!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\namae\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,

...(omittion for viewing)  

line 662, in lockfile_content
    return self.load_lockfile()
  File "c:\users\namae\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pipenv\project.py", line 1054, in load_lockfile
    j["_meta"]["sources"][i]["url"]
KeyError: 'url'
```

### Output file

On the directory C:\Users\namae\OneDrive\Document\test, two files are created - "pipfile" and "pipfile.lock".

pipfile

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]

[packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.8"
```

pipfile.lock

```
{
    "_meta": {
        "hash": {
            "sha256": "c2384ad47b0fded84aa8d567ff10e9e32bb6e8da4cb9d05c0b5403e63a1f10f9"
        },
        "pipfile-spec": 6,
        "requires": {},
        "sources": [
            {}
        ]
    },
    "default": {},
    "develop": {}
}
```

### Environment

Windows10 home

Comment: Have you tried deleting the Pipfile.lock and retrying `pipenv install` ?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried that, but anything was unchanged.